# MYSQL Query to select strings from a column

Tags: php, mysql

I have this content in a **single** MYSQL database column:

```
[Item: Coca-Cola Price: K8.00 Quantity 3, Item: Coca-Cola Price: K8.00 Quantity 1, Item: Coca-Cola Price: K8.00 Quantity 10, Item: Cheese burger Price: K37.00 Quantity 2, Item: Grand Chicken Garlic Mayo Price: K36.00 Quantity 3]
```

I'm trying to find a way in which I can pick the `Item`, `Price` and `Quantity` as separate columns. This is an attempt:

```
select items
 , mid(
     items, 
     instr(items, @start_delim) + length(@start_delim),
     length(items) - instr(items, @end_delim) - 1
   ) as item_name from (select @start_delim := 'Item:', @end_delim := 'Price: ') as init , orders'
```

At the moment I've just tried with getting the contents between `Item:` and `Price:` but all I'm getting everything.

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you try to fetch data with your query? if yes, then please show your query.

Comment: At the moment I've just tried with getting the contents between Item: and Price: but all I'm getting everything.

Comment: Whoah ..... waaaaait. You mean ONE FIELD in your database has ALL of that data??? You may want to re-edit your question to put that table breakout format back into the string then. We all's got confused by the data you presented.

Comment: @IncredibleHat Yeah!

Comment: Ok, so yeah, this will be a tricky one to do solely inside a SQL statement. REGEX may be needed. Curious why this was stored this way in the first place, but that doesn't change the question. If you are converting this data out into a new table structure, you could do it all inside PHP with a conversion script.

Comment: Ok the thing is that I'm get Orders from a mobile app and they are being sent as an Array and stored like that. Maybe I 'm using a wrong approach to this but I just want to find a way in which one row can contain the order details so that I can display them in a table @IncredibleHat

Comment: Ah, right. You should store the items into a order_items table as rows with a foreign key (the foreign key being the order id from the orders table). That way you can search the items table if you need too, and also pull what you want, directly, and cleanly.

Comment: If you can modify the database, this field really needs to be cut into other tables and foreing keys, like IncredibleHat mentionned.  Otherwise, get the entire line out and process it in your PHP.  Much simpler to do pattern matching in PHP and build a query to do it.

Comment: is it always 5 in a column or does it vary?

Comment: @IncredibleHat, I'll try doing that, because, these items are coming from an sqlite database as one order request

Comment: @Cemal it varies....